# Bitmap not displaying properly android?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, convolution, renderscript

I'm trying to display a bitmap that's been processed through a ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3 edge detection matrix. But instead of the dark image you would expect from the convolution, its displaying *extremely* light.

heres a screenshot:
http://tinypic.com/r/x4etl1/8

compared to what I want:
http://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/46

Here's my code that deals with the image:

```
private void renderImage(){
    renderScript = RenderScript.create(this);
    renderedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalImage.getWidth(), originalImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    tempIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, originalImage);
    tempOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, renderedImage);
    convolve = ScriptIntrinsicConvolve3x3.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
    float[] coefficients = {-1f, -1f, -1f, -1f, 8f, -1f, -1f, -1f, -1f};
    convolve.setCoefficients(coefficients);
    convolve.setInput(tempIn);
    convolve.forEach(tempOut);
    tempOut.copyTo(renderedImage);

    renderScript.destroy();

}

private void setView(){
    ImageView imgView = new ImageView(this);

    imgView.setImageBitmap(renderedImage);


    setContentView(imgView);
}
```

Any suggestions as to why this is happening? 
I've tried taking pixel samples and the bitmap is dominated by 0s, but shouldn't those be black?

Comment: Idk why I didn't try this earlier but I set the image view background to black and it produces exactly the output it should. That doesn't solve the question, though, of why the convolution is resulting in transparency?

Comment: Assuming your input is a normal bitmap the Alpha channel would be all 1.f (255).  With your kernel that would convolve to an alpha of 0.f.  You can either set the alpha back or display you bitmap without transparency enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried `BitmapDrawable opaqueImage = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), renderedImage);
        opaqueImage.setAlpha(255);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(opaqueImage);` but that did nothing, and when I checked the alpha value of `opaqueImage` _before_ setting it to 255, it was already set to 255. however, `opaqueImage.getOpacity` returns `-3` which is translucent..